# Geometric mean in SAS for each column of a data set

Tags: sas, geometric-mean

Suppose I have the following SAS data set

```
data have; 
input id$ x1 x2 x3;
datalines;
1 10 5 15
2 15 10 7
3 12 10 9
4 14 15 10
;
run;
```

I would like to calculate the geometric mean, geometric coefficient of variation (formula is `100*(exp(ASD^2)-1)^0.5` ASD is the arithmetic SD of log-transformed data.) of each variable `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`.  How can  I perform these operations?
As I am completely new in SAS, I would appreciate  your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*Compute log value of x1, x2, x3;
data tab1;
  set have;

  logx1=log(x1); 
  logx2=log(x2); 
  logx3=log(x3); 
run;

*Compute SD of logx1, logx2, logx3;
proc means data=tab1 noprint;
  var logx1-logx3;
  output out=tab2 n=n1-n3 std=std1-std3;
run;

*Compute logcv using formula;
data tab3;
  set tab2;

  logcv1=100*(exp(std1**2)-1)**0.5;
  logcv2=100*(exp(std2**2)-1)**0.5;
  logcv3=100*(exp(std3**2)-1)**0.5;
  putlog 'NOTE: ' logcv1= logcv2= logcv3=;
run;
```

The result is show in log window:

```
NOTE: logcv1=18.155613536 logcv2=48.09165987 logcv3=32.538955751
```

It not much diffcult to do caculation in SAS, just try to do it step by step and you will get it.

Comment: What function is used to calculate the product value of each column. I mean product of all values in X1, similar for x2 and X3

Comment: @Uddin No function do that. `proc means` just calculates the standard deviation for logx1-logx3, it is a bulit in procedure and does not calculate the product value.